# How to add vertical scroll bar to the image that is displayed in a Bootstrap tool-tip?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using **Bootstrap framework v 3.3.0** for my website.

I'm showing an image in a tool-tip but as this image size is big I want to add vertical scroll bars for it so that the user can see the image by scrolling up and down. During this scroll motion the tool-tip should not get hide. How to achieve this?

Following is the code I tried for showing an image into a Bootstrap tool-tip:

HTML code:

```
<div class="input-group">  
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stud_id" id="stud_id"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" rel="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<img src='localhost/img/demo_image.jpg' width='150' height='250'/>"></a>    
    </span>
  </div>
```

jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-group-addon').tooltip({
    selector: "a[rel=tooltip]",
    placement: "bottom"
  })
});
```

I'm displaying the image at the bottom of the icon.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/z9vd9tk1/1/

**CSS**

```
.tooltip-inner {
    max-height:150px!important;
    overflow-y:scroll
}
```

**JQ**

```
//indicates whether the mouse over tooltip
var hover = false;
//for convenience
var $TT = $('.input-group-addon');


$TT.tooltip({
    selector: "a[rel=tooltip]",
    placement: "bottom"
})

**JQ**

$('body').on('mouseenter', '.tooltip,a[rel=tooltip]', function () {
    hover = true;
})
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.tooltip', function () {

    hover = false;
    //$TT.tooltip('hide') dont work;
    $('.tooltip').hide();
})

//if hover is true hover prevents the tooltip close
$TT.on('hide.bs.tooltip', function () {
    if (hover == true) return false;
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dm4web. You have done the magic for me. Your answer has been accepted and upvoted too. Thank you so much once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add one more option in javascript like this:

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-group-addon').tooltip({
    selector: "a[rel=tooltip]",
    placement: "bottom",
    template : '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>'+
               '<div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
  })
});


And you can apply any CSS whatever you want. I got this from here      
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

I hope it will solve your problem
```

Comment: I tried your jQuery code by adding template attribute. But it's not adding vertical scroll bar to the tool-tip image. Same is the result as before with my code.